# Mac OS X - Passing pathname with spaces as arguments to bashscript and then issue open Terminal command

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, automator

## Problem Using bash shell on Mac OS X Mavericks

I created a bash script called `test.sh` that accepts one command line argument:-

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
open -a Terminal $1
```

When i execute this script in the following way:-

```
$ ./test.sh /Users/myusername/Desktop/folderwithoutspaces/
```

it executes perfectly and launches a new Terminal window in the given folder.

But when i execute this script in the following way:-

```
$ ./test.sh /Users/myusername/Desktop/folder\ withspaces/
```

it fails to open a new Terminal window and shows the following error message:-

```
The files /Users/myusername/Desktop/folder and /Users/myusername/Desktop/withspaces do not exist.
```

I tried all these possible ways but wasn't successful at any:-

```
$ ./test.sh "/Users/myusername/Desktop/folder\ withspaces/"
$ ./test.sh "/Users/myusername/Desktop/folder withspaces/"
$ ./test.sh '/Users/myusername/Desktop/folder\ withspaces/'
$ ./test.sh '/Users/myusername/Desktop/folder withspaces/'
$ ./test.sh /Users/myusername/Desktop/folder\ withspaces/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the variable with quoting, it gets split based on `IFS` (which includes a whitespace by default).  The solution is to quote the variable.  Instead of saying:

```
open -a Terminal $1
```

say:

```
open -a Terminal "$1"
```