# Open a Terminal window with Java

Tags: java, macos, terminal, window

I am aware that you can pass commands to the Terminal and it returns your result in Java. The problem is for undisclosed reasons I need a Terminal window to open and to have the command in it. This code works to open an empty Terminal window (on mac):

`p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/open -a Terminal");`

And I have seen someone say on a different overflow question that you can do this:

`p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/open -a Terminal [Put Command to pass through here]");`

But it didn't seem to work when I tried to pass the command through to the window.

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: Are you working on osx ?

Comment: See this question and answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496182/mac-os-x-passing-pathname-with-spaces-as-arguments-to-bashscript-and-then-issu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using **[AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/AppleScriptX.html)**.

Here you can find example how call it from Java:
[AppleScript from Java on Mac OS X 10.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159719/applescript-from-java-on-mac-os-x-10-6)

And script you need will look like this:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set currentTab to do script ("cd ~/Downloads/")
    set currentTab to do script ("ll")
end tell
```