# csc -version is running in terminal but not from my java program MAC

Tags: java, linux, macos, javafx

```
package test_cmd_command;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;


public class CommandLine {

public static String executeCommand(String cliCommand) {
    String s = null;
    BufferedReader stdInput = null;
    BufferedReader stdError = null;
    String error = "";
    String output = "";
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb1 = new ProcessBuilder(
                "bash",
                "-c",
                cliCommand);

        pb1.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = pb1.start();

        stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            output += "\n" + s;
        }
        //System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(">> "+s.toString());
            error += "\n" + s;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("exception happened - here's what I know: \n" + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            stdInput.close();
            stdError.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
    String returnValue = null;
    if (output != null && error != null) {
        returnValue = output + "\n" + ":  " + error;
    } else if (output != null) {
        returnValue = output;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
}
```

**"csc -version"** is running in terminal but not from my java program on MAC.
it give Output **"bash Command Not Found"**.
Is any way to solve this issue....
This program run other commands correctly like **javac -version** etc.
I am running this program on **MAC not on windows**.

Comment: I guess there is no "cmd" on MacOS' bash? In the bash you run "csc -version", but in your code you actually run in a bash "cmd /c csc -version" ... Have you tried `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cliCommand);` ? Just a guess, not familiar with MacOS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a Terminal window with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23956389/open-a-terminal-window-with-java)

Comment: @AccessDenied Its not working for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work for me

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Versions/bin/:${PATH}
```

I run command like this **"export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Versions/bin/:${PATH}; csc -version"** and it works and return version of csc.